# Xamarin forms TranslationY breaks AdjustPan on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

We have a situation in our App that we need to translate some content for performance reasons (To stop layout changes occurring during animation).

The problem we have found is that having any TranslationY on our content causes the keyboard to cover our Entry's. I've replicated this in a blank Xamarin Forms project with the following MainPage.Xaml.

```
<ScrollView Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" TranslationY="60">
        <Entry BackgroundColor="Blue" />
        <Entry BackgroundColor="Black"/>
        <Entry BackgroundColor="Blue"/>
        <Entry BackgroundColor="Black"/>
        <Entry BackgroundColor="Blue"/>
        <Entry BackgroundColor="Black"/>
        <Entry BackgroundColor="Blue"/>
        <Entry BackgroundColor="Black"/>
        <Entry BackgroundColor="Blue"/>
        <Entry BackgroundColor="Black"/>
        <Entry BackgroundColor="Blue" />
        <Entry BackgroundColor="Black"/>
        <Entry BackgroundColor="Blue"/>
        <Entry BackgroundColor="Black"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

On my Pixel 2XL, when I click on the final black entry nothing moves at all and the entry is hidden behind the keyboard. If I do the exact same thing without the TranslationY, the entry is pushed up above the keyboard as expected.

I couldn't find any other posts about this specifically. Is this a known issue and something we have to work around? Or should I be submitting this as a bug to Xamarin?

Note this seems to work fine on both UWP + iOS, it just seems to be an android issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soft keyboard coverage is a known issue for Android.You could try to replace `TranslationY` with `Margin` to constrain the location of StackLayout.

```
<ScrollView Orientation="Vertical">
  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,60,0,0">
    <Entry BackgroundColor="Blue" />
    <Entry BackgroundColor="Black"/>
    <Entry BackgroundColor="Blue"/>
    <Entry BackgroundColor="Black"/>
    <Entry BackgroundColor="Blue"/>
    <Entry BackgroundColor="Black"/>
    <Entry BackgroundColor="Blue"/>
    <Entry BackgroundColor="Black"/>
    <Entry BackgroundColor="Blue"/>
    <Entry BackgroundColor="Black"/>
    <Entry BackgroundColor="Blue" />
    <Entry BackgroundColor="Black"/>
    <Entry BackgroundColor="Blue"/>
    <Entry BackgroundColor="Black"/>
   </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We did end up changing it to use a margin instead of translation, but we use it in an animation. Changing the margin causes Layout Changed events, which is not acceptable for us due to the large number of controls being moved. We've opted for animating with Translation during the animation, then swapping to a margin once that is finished. Thanks for the answer though, as long as it's something that's a known issue.